# Adding in additional capturing groups to a regex for 'readbility'

Tags: regex

I have a hard time making sense of where alternations start/end (especially on very long regexes) and tend to add in parentheticals only for my own comprehension of them. For example:

```
\w+\.(?!bat|exe)\w+   # this is a simple regex that's clear anyways, but using it to show the point
```

And I will often write this as:

```
\w+\.(?!(bat|exe))\w+
```

Additionally, I find this easier to read than using a non-capturing group, which is probably more "correct" than the capture grouping I have above:

```
\w+\.(?!(?:bat|exe))\w+
```

My question is, are there any reasons why adding additional parentheses would be considered a bad idea? Normally if I have to capture anything I use named groups so I'm not concerned about the group-index of captured groups.

---

Perhaps a better example would be a regex like:

```
\w+\.psd|psd_exe
```

For me it would "look like" match a string such as `file.psd` or `file.psd_exe`, instead of what it actually does is match `file.psd` or `psd_exe`. So to me I'd prefer to write it as:

```
(\w+\.psd)|psd_exe
```

To make it more clear, if not in verbose mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost always increasing readability is a good thing. I don't see any negatives to your approach other than having additional capture groups—if that can be considered "bad".

Performance change is likely to be negligible.